# Getting "'TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined" while connecting oracledb

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I Want to connect the oracle database for my project, tried with the code below,  Getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined"

using oracledb package and sharing the typescript code, What may be the issue?

```
import * as oracledb from 'oracledb'
export class Connectdb {
connection: any
result:any
constructor() {
    this.connection = oracledb.getConnection({
        user: "user",
        password: "pass",
        connectString: "138.21.146.216:12345/bomdevo01"
    });
}
}

new Connectdb()
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the piece of code you are getting error in?

Comment: changed the import  to import oracledb from 'oracledb', now it is working, Thanks @AkshayM